# Cómo recibir un JSON en Angular

Tags: json, angular

Buen día, quiero consumir una Rest en angular que retorna un json de este estilo

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "recetarios" : [ {
      "titulo" : "Comidas Frias",
      "id" : 1 ... }
```

En el onInit tengo esto y NO funciona

```
    this.servicio.getRecetas()
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data.content);
        this.recetas = data.content;
      }
    );
  }
```

Alguien sabe qué debería cambiar en el OnInit para guardarlo en this.recetas?

Comment: que quieres decir que no funciona? si `data` contiene es el json que has puesto deberías acceder a las recetas así `data._embedded.recetarios` y no usar `content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que estas recibiendo en el servicio lo estas pasando sin ningun `pipe` entonces deberías hacer:

```
 this.servicio.getRecetas()
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data.content);
        this.recetas = data.content._embedded.recetarios;
      }
    );
  }
```

Esto es suponiendo que  `console.log(data.content);` verdaderamente está imprimiendo lo que pones como `JSON`.